# Vue: Event Methods- Confusion

Tags: events, vue.js, method-signature

I have a parent Vue which enables or disables "edit" mode. In non-edit mode all components are read only.

I've implemented this via a data object and all works fine.

I've split out some of the components in child components.

From the parent an $emit message is sent with the new edit mode state:

```
  methods: {
    toggleMode () {
      this.editMode = !this.editMode
      this.$emit('edit-mode-change', this.editMode)
    }
```

Using Vue DevTools I can see the message is emitted.

However, I can't seem to receive it in my child component!I've looked a the docs, but none of the examples match this case. This is what I have currently (*in the child component*):

```
 methods: {
   onEditModeChange: function (mode) {
     console.log('mode is', mode)
     this.editMode = mode
   }
```

Also tried:

```
 events: {
   onEditModeChange: function (mode) {
     console.log('mode is', mode)
     this.editMode = mode
   }
```

Plus I'm getting an browser console error as follows:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "edit-mode-change": got false 
(found in <Dimensions> at /home/anthony/Projects/Towers-Vue/src/components/assets/Dimensions.vue)
```

I'm sure I'm doing something basic wrong, but the docs don't reference the events: {} block, yet I've seen it on other code. Nor does it show how to implement a listener.

Thanks for taking the time to view this post, if you can point me in the right direction, it's much appreciated.

Comment: Is this with Vue 1 or Vue 2?

Comment: Vue 2. Apologies forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vue 2, events only flow laterally or up, not down.

What you really want is to simply pass a prop into your components.

In the parent JS:

```js
toggleMode () {
    this.editMode = ! this.editMode;
}
```

In the parent template:

```html
<child-component-1 :editMode="editMode"></child-component-1>
...same for others...
```

Then simply accept `editMode` as a prop in each of your child components:

```js
{
    props: ['editMode']
}
```

You can now use `editMode` within your child's template. It'll track the parent's `editMode`, so no need for manual events/watchers.

Comment: Thanks! That solved it, plus it's wonderfully simple like the rest of Vue.

Answer (score 1):

The way vue2 works is by having a one-direction flow of the data, from parent to child, so in your parent component you can have

```
<template>
 <child-component :isEditing="editMode"></child-component>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    methods: {
        toggleMode () {
          this.editMode = !this.editMode
          this.$emit('edit-mode-change', this.editMode)
        }
    }
}
```

and in child component you use props to get the data

```
Vue.component('child-component', {
  props: ['isEditing'],
  template: '<span>edit mode: {{ isEditing }}</span>'
})
```

we have cover the edit mode for the child. now if you want to send data from child to parent, then child needs to "emit" a signal to the parent, as props are "read only"

in child component you do at any point

```
someMethod() {
    this.$emit('editDone', dataEdited);
}
```

and in your parent component you "intercept" the message using on:

```
<template>
    <child-component 
        :isEditing="editMode"
        @editDone="someParentMethod"></child-component>
</template>
```

Greetings!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It helped clear things up more.

Comment: Your approach will definitely be useful later on, especially for more complex parent / child interactions. For now, I simply need to enable edit mode in the children. But I can see a case where the parent would need to know the state of the child.